# Cannot deploy war file to a specific folder on a Weblogic 12c server

Tags: java, war, weblogic12c

I am trying to manually deploy a war file onto a Weblogic 12c server thru the Admin Console.
I can get it to successfully deploy when I accept the default path but I would like to deploy it on another folder. Below is a screen shot of the Admin Console to upload the file:
[image]

When I try to change the path, by removing the **.war** after the folder **upload** from the **tms-messaging-service** from the Admin Console displays the error:
**You must select an application before continuing**

The folder does exist but I cannot change the path.  Why can't I change the path of the file deployment?

If I keep the default path, the Console deploys the application as the path is written. There is a war file in the **upload** directory then an **app** folder then the war file is in the **app** folder.

Is there anyway to change the path that deploys this war file?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the right access rights for the folder you want Weblogic to use? You need to find the user that Weblogic runs with and compare that to the folder permissions.

Comment: Thanks.   That helped.  Now I can deploy in the folder that I wanted to